# Any way to scale my application UI down?

Tags: android, xml

I developed my application specifically for 10" tablets.

I used DP mostly, and some weighting for other elements, however; I'm unable to use an AVD but I have my Nexus 4. The UI looks gigantic on my phone, due to the DP. Is there any way to scale DP without rewriting my code? Some sort of manifest scale?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There's no way. I advise you to run the emulator with a big screen (10') and a lower DPI. (QVGA for example), you might find it possible to work with it that way, and it will reflect good the app dimensions.

Comment: I wish the 10" would load, for some reason only the Nexus 7 AVD loads... any tips?

Comment: Can you edit your AVD to have a QVGA resolution? or a lower DPI? It will help your computer digest the device

Comment: Yeah, I even made it screen resolution; however, I can't get the 'android' loading thing to show up. It shows up almost immediately with the Nexus 7 AVD.